# How to get location of textarea in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtextarea

I have created a **JFrame** containing 2 `JPanels(panel1,panel2)`.i have added panel2 in panel1.
panel1.add(panel2);

i have added a text area into panel2.

```
panel2.add(textarea);
```

finally panel1 to getContentPane

```
getContentPane().add(panel1);
```

now i am getting the location of textarea by

textarea.getLocation();

i have created a Save button which saves the textarea(x,y) values.i am using xml to store (x,y) values.

now when i close and reopen the jar file the textarea place is not changed but the xml values are showing the changed textarea location values .

how to solve??

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`Component#getLocation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocation%28%29)?

Answer (score 2):

Try `textarea.getLocation()` or `textarea.getLocationOnScreen()` to get the top left corner, then use `getSize()` to calculate how far the textarea extends.